# Get docker API engine exec output

Tags: curl, docker

I try to get the output from a command Im running inside a container, but I only get it in RAW text so far. I need to be able to get the output with PHP, seems like I cant do that when it returns in RAW text.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.19

CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

WORKDIR /root

RUN sed -i "s/^exit 101$/exit 0/" /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

RUN apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get install -y \
    nginx \
    php-fpm php-mysql php-gd php-curl php-cli php-mbstring php-dom unzip

RUN service php7.0-fpm start

EXPOSE 80

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

And here is the curl requests Im running:

```
## Create container
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Image":"test-container","Env":["VIRTUAL_HOST=test.domain.dev"]}' -X POST http:/v1.27/containers/create?name=test.domain.dev

## Start container
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http:/v1.27/containers/test.domain.dev/start

## Create exec instance
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "AttachStdin":false,"AttachStdout":true,"AttachStderr":true, "Tty":false, "Cmd":["/bin/bash", "-c", "date"] }' -X POST http:/v1.27/containers/test.domain.dev/exec

## Start exec instance
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "Detach": false, "Tty": false }' -X POST http:/v1.27/exec/bcd34186a9a7360809cace3674fec03bd1c70c1c453be24ad058a03fa0b0e960/start

// Sun Mar 26 23:23:53 UTC 2017
```

Output from `docker info`:

```
Containers: 8
Running: 4
Paused: 0
Stopped: 4
Images: 152
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 977c511eda0925a723debdc94d09459af49d082a
runc version: a01dafd48bc1c7cc12bdb01206f9fea7dd6feb70
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
seccomp
Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.12-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.952 GiB
Name: moby
ID: JNZW:S7LC:4JRG:M3K3:6EFV:RZNR:Q7T5:XNJA:LB2Z:PO5G:PGPX:RI2E
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
File Descriptors: 43
Goroutines: 81
System Time: 2017-03-26T23:25:45.809302866Z
EventsListeners: 2
No Proxy: *.local, 169.254/16
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

So, is there any proper way to get this output? Thanks for any help

Comment: Has anybody found an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am set "AttachStdout" in true and "Tty" in true, when create exec instance. 
In the request start exec i am set "Tty" in true.

This shows me the values in the tty but I can't capture it from an application.

```
# Create the exec
#
EXEC_CREATE=`curl --silent --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http:/containers/${CONTAINER_NAME}/exec" -XPOST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "AttachStdout": true,
    "Tty": true,
    "Cmd": [ "ruby", "-e", "5.times { puts :hi; sleep 1 }"]
  }'
`
echo $EXEC_CREATE | jq '.'

# Run the exec
#
EXEC_ID=$(echo $EXEC_CREATE | jq -r '.Id')
curl --silent --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http:/exec/${EXEC_ID}/start" -XPOST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "Detach": false,
    "Tty": true
  }'
```

[taken from](https://gist.github.com/dapplebeforedawn/7733a6486f02d21f68053c0c1e43431f)